# format_currency and symbol position

Tags: internationalization, symfony1

I'm trying to display a spanish price. Spanish prices have the currency symbol AFTER the 
number, but Symfony insists in placing it before...

Is there any way to move it after the number?

Thanks!

Comment: By the way, I'm using Symfony 1.4
This: format_currency('300000', '€', 'es_ES'), is showing this: € 300.000,00

Comment: I definetely think it's a bug, because I tried with 'fr_FR' and then the symbol is placed after the number. I'll report it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a bug. It will be solved probably in the next version.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the `format_currency` function the culture parameter:

```
<?php echo format_currency('30.00', '€', 'es_ES'); ?>
```

will produce:

```
30.00€
```

Here, 'es_ES' is your country and language combination. If you are unfamiliar with this then [read up on symfony and cultures](http://www.symfony-project.org/book/1_1/13-I18n-and-L10n).

Comment: I'd still recommend to read http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Doctrine/en/19 before reading a bit outdated docs.

Comment: It wasn't clear what version of symfony was being used, and the Definitive Guide is still the best symfony reference. *shrug*

Comment: It's not working. I'm using Symfony 1.4, and of course I have read the official docs and the API (even the source code of the method).
I'm using this: format_currency('300000', '€', 'es_ES'), and it's producing this: € 300.000,00

Comment: I can see it for sf1.4 too. I've checked the es.dat file for problems, but can't find a discrepancy between it and the es.dat files from other symfony versions. I think you may need to raise a ticket with the symfony developers: http://trac.symfony-project.org/report/1

Answer (score 1):

The `ICU/CLDR` that is used by symfony to determine the position of the currency symbol is wrong for the `es_ES` culture.

You need to patch the `/lib/vend/symfony/i18n/data/es.dat` file

Search for this string

```
s:12:"Â¤Â #,##0.00"
```

and change it for this other

```
s:12:"#,##0.00Â Â¤"
```